# Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-anydpi-v21/ic_upsc.xml

Tags: java, android

i have created an app by using SVG and PNG Images it is perfectly working in android 5.1 and android 6.0 but other other version like android 4.4, 7.1 and 8.1 application crash and show me this error:

**Fatal exception:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ejobbox.ejobbox/com.ejobbox.ejobbox.DrawerMenu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ejobbox.ejobbox, PID: 8648
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ejobbox.ejobbox/com.ejobbox.ejobbox.DrawerMenu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.ejobbox.ejobbox:drawable/ic_upsc with resource ID #0x7f0700a2
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-anydpi-v21/ic_upsc.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0700a2

    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
```

I am currently using android studio 3.0 version so please let me know how can i fix it. i have added

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

but the error is not fixed, so please help me to resolve this error.

### activity_drawer_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawermenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ejobbox.ejobbox.DrawerMenu">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/backgroundcolor"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_add1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/cardbackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/LayerImg1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="?attr/cardbackground"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="2dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img1"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/border"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_letestjob" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/badgeCount"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/img1"
                            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img1"
                            android:layout_marginRight="-2dip"
                            android:layout_marginTop="-2dip"
                            android:background="@drawable/item_count"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#FFF"
                            android:textSize="10sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:text="10"
                            android:visibility="visible" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ltsjobs"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/img1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/txtborder"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                        android:paddingRight="3dp"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp"
                        android:text="Latest Jobs"
                        android:textColor="?attr/icontextcolor"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/BankingIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/cardbackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/LayerBanking"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="?attr/cardbackground"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="2dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/BankingLogo"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/border"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_banking" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/BankingBadge"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/BankingLogo"
                            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/BankingLogo"
                            android:layout_marginRight="-2dip"
                            android:layout_marginTop="-2dip"
                            android:background="@drawable/item_count"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#FFF"
                            android:textSize="11sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/BankingTxt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/BankingLogo"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/txtborder"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                        android:paddingRight="3dp"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp"
                        android:text="Banking"
                        android:textColor="?attr/icontextcolor"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/PoliceIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/cardbackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/LayerPolice"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="?attr/cardbackground"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="2dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/PoliceLogo"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/border"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_police" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/PoliceBadge"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/PoliceLogo"
                            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/PoliceLogo"
                            android:layout_marginRight="-2dip"
                            android:layout_marginTop="-2dip"
                            android:background="@drawable/item_count"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#FFF"
                            android:textSize="11sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/PoliceTxt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/PoliceLogo"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/txtborder"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                        android:paddingRight="3dp"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp"
                        android:text="Police"
                        android:textColor="?attr/icontextcolor"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationMenuView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="?attr/backgroundcolor"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:itemIconTint="?attr/tintcolor"
        app:itemTextColor="?attr/textcolor"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

### DrawerMenu.java

```
package com.ejobbox.ejobbox;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;

import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.renderscript.Sampler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ejobbox.ejobbox.Helper.LocalHelper;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;
import com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import cc.cloudist.acplibrary.ACProgressConstant;
import cc.cloudist.acplibrary.ACProgressPie;
import in.galaxyofandroid.spinerdialog.OnSpinerItemClick;
import in.galaxyofandroid.spinerdialog.SpinnerDialog;
import io.paperdb.Paper;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;


public class DrawerMenu extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ArrayList<Model> list;
    private String baseURL = "http://ejobbox.com/";
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private NavigationView navMenuView;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
    Context context;
    boolean doubleBackToExitPressed = false;
    SharedPref sharedpref;
    SharedPref Languagepref;
    private float cVersion;
    private String Applink;
    private boolean is_first=true;
    private String cVer;
    private Menu menu;

    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> Qualiitems = new ArrayList<>();
    SpinnerDialog spinnerDialog;
    SpinnerDialog spinnerDialogQuali;
    ImageView imageView;
    int GetMenuid;

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Datakey";
    public static final String PREFS_NAME2 = "Updatekey";

    private CardView BtnAdd1, BtnAdd2, BtnAdd3, BtnAdd4, BtnAdd5, BtnAdd6, BtnAdd7, BtnAdd8, BtnAdd9, BtnAdd10, BtnAdd11, BtnAdd12, BtnAdd13, BtnAdd14, BtnAdd15, BtnAdd16, BtnAdd17, BtnAdd18;
    int getBadgedataInt;
    int getOLDVALUEInt;
    int jobResponseValue;
    int ResultUpd = 0;

    int BankingValue;
    int getBankingOLD;
    int BankingResult = 0;

    int ResultValue, AdmitCardValue, PoliceValue, RailwayValue, SscValue, UpscValue, DefenceValue, ITComputerValue, EngereeningValue, MedicalValue, SPSCValue, ITIValue, TeacherValue, InterviewValue, AdmitionValue, OtherjobValue;
    int getResultOLD, getAdmitCardOLD, getPoliceOLD, getRailwayOLD, getSscOLD, getUpscOLD, getITComputerOLD, getDefenceOLD, getEngereeningOLD, getMedicalOLD, getSPSCOLD, getITIOLD, getTeacherOLD, getInterviewOLD, getAdmitionOLD, getOtherjobOLD;
    int ResultResult = 0, AdmitResult = 0, PoliceResult = 0, RailwayResult = 0, SscResult = 0, UpscResult = 0, ITComputerResult = 0, DefenceResult = 0, EngereeningResult = 0, MedicalResult = 0, ITIResult = 0, SPSCResult = 0, TeacherResult = 0, InterviewResult = 0, AdmitionResult = 0, OtherjobResult = 0;

    TextView ltsJobs, TextLang, BankingTxt, PoliceTxt, RailwayTxt, Ssctxt, UpscTxt, ITItxt, DefenceTxt, ITTxt, Teachertxt, InterviewTxt, AdmitionTxt, EngerTxt, MedicalTxt, spscTxt, OtherTxt, ResultTxt, AdmitTxt,StateTxt,QualiTxt;
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocalHelper.onAttach(newBase, "en"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        sharedpref = new SharedPref(this);
        if (sharedpref.loadNightModeState() == true) {
            setTheme(R.style.darktheme);
        } else setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_menu);

        android.widget.Toolbar toolbar=(android.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("EJOBBOX");

        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
        checkInternetConenction();

        //TODO:Google ADS sense
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        // todo: Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance.
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        mFirebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
        mFirebaseAnalytics.setMinimumSessionDuration(20000);

        final TextView badge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.badgeCount);
        final TextView Banking = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BankingBadge);
        final TextView Railway = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RailwayBadge);
        final TextView Police = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PoliceBadge);
        final TextView SSC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SscBadge);
        final TextView UPSC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.UpscBadge);


        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawermenu);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        navMenuView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationMenuView);
        mToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        BtnAdd1 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card_add1);
        BtnAdd2 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.BankingIcon);
        BtnAdd3 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.PoliceIcon);
        BtnAdd4 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.RailwayIcon);
        BtnAdd5 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.SscIcon);
        BtnAdd6 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.UpscIcon);


        //add Click Listner
        BtnAdd1.setOnClickListener(this);
        BtnAdd2.setOnClickListener(this);
        BtnAdd3.setOnClickListener(this);
        BtnAdd4.setOnClickListener(this);
        BtnAdd5.setOnClickListener(this);
        BtnAdd6.setOnClickListener(this);


        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editors = sharedPreferences.edit();

        navMenuView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Intent MenuIntent;
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.Alljobs:
                        MenuIntent = new Intent(DrawerMenu.this, AllJobsPage.class);
                        MenuIntent.putExtra("UpdResult", String.valueOf(jobResponseValue));
                        MenuIntent.putExtra("jobID", "190");
                        MenuIntent.putExtra("JOBSSTATE", R.string.All_jobs);
                        startActivity(MenuIntent);
                        break;
                    case R.id.countdown:
                        MenuIntent = new Intent(DrawerMenu.this, ExamCountdown.class);
                        startActivity(MenuIntent);
                        break;
                    case R.id.jobsummary:
                        MenuIntent = new Intent(DrawerMenu.this, JobSummary.class);
                        startActivity(MenuIntent);
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


    //TODO: Check Internet Connection [End]

    private void initItems() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            items.add(this.getResources().getString(R.string.All_india));
            items.add(this.getResources().getString(R.string.AndraPradesh));
            items.add(this.getResources().getString(R.string.ArunachalPrades));
            items.add(this.getResources().getString(R.string.Assam));
            items.add(this.getResources().getString(R.string.Bihar));
        }
    }

    private void eduQulification() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            Qualiitems.add(this.getResources().getString(R.string.ssc));
            Qualiitems.add(this.getResources().getString(R.string.hsc));
            Qualiitems.add(this.getResources().getString(R.string.Diploma));
            Qualiitems.add(this.getResources().getString(R.string.ITI));
            Qualiitems.add(this.getResources().getString(R.string.Graduate));

        }
    }
    // Searching With Spinner[END]


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       GetMenuid= v.getId();
        Intent i;

      // i = new Intent(this, police.class);
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.card_add1:
                    i = new Intent(this, AllJobsPage.class);
                    i.putExtra("UpdResult", String.valueOf(jobResponseValue));
                    i.putExtra("jobID", "190");
                    i.putExtra("JOBSSTATE", R.string.All_jobs);
                    startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.BankingIcon:
                i = new Intent(this, police.class);
                i.putExtra("BankingUPD",String.valueOf(BankingValue));
                i.putExtra("jobID","197");
                i.putExtra("JOBSSTATE",this.getResources().getString(R.string.Banking_Jobs));
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.PoliceIcon:
                i = new Intent(this, police.class);
                i.putExtra("PoliceUPD",String.valueOf(PoliceValue));
                i.putExtra("jobID","198");
                i.putExtra("JOBSSTATE",this.getResources().getString(R.string.Police_Jobs));
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    private void setSupportActionBar(android.widget.Toolbar toolbar) {
        if(getSupportActionBar()!=null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    //TODO: Actionbar Share Button
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.memu_items,menu);
        MenuItem menushare=menu.findItem(R.id.sharMenu);
        ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menushare);
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,DrawerMenu.this.getResources().getString(R.string.shareTitle));
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, DrawerMenu.this.getResources().getString(R.string.shareContent)+"\n"+DrawerMenu.this.getResources().getString(R.string.applink));
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(sharingIntent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

move all drawables located in the folder "/res/drawable-anydpi-v21" into the normal drawable folder.

See also error message line:
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-anydpi-v21/ic_upsc.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0700a2

To support the different resolutions of image files, it is best to use the following folders:

- drawable-ldpi
- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-xhdpi
- drawable-xxhdpi
- drawable-xxxhdpi

Hope that could solve your problem

Comment: Ok i will try your suggestion and i hope it will work :)